# How can I implement a display for all gifs on an iOS device in objective c using photos framework

Tags: ios, objective-c

Facebook messenger, among file/image attachment browser has a "gif" button which displays all gifs saved on the device (anything you ever viewed it seems)

I'd like to implement the same thing and since assets library is deprecated now I'm looking into the photos framework to accomplish this, however it seems there's no way to query for gifs only

the only thing I can do is query for all images and while iterating over each one to check their UTI which doesn't seem efficient

any thoughts on how to query for gifs specifically?